# NextJS File Based Routing with dynamic portion

Tags: next.js

I am working on a site that uses a single CMS but splits the site multiple sites, but that use the same template. Here is an example:

```
mysite.com/company1/news/[articles]
mysite.com/company1/products/[products]
mysite.com/company1/team/[team]

mysite.com/company2/news/[articles]
mysite.com/company2/products/[products]
mysite.com/company2/team/[team]

mysite.com/company3/news/[articles]
mysite.com/company3/products/[products]
mysite.com/company3/team/[team]
```

Each template (articles, products, team, etc) is the same for all sites, it just grabs the data from a different location. We also support multiple languages using a 2 character language code - if not language is specified, then it assumed english:

```
mysite.com/company1/news/[articles] (english)
mysite.com/company1/fr/news/[articles] (french)
mysite.com/company1/ko/news/[articles] (korean)
mysite.com/company2/fr/news/[articles] (french)
etc
```

Is it possible to structure this using the routing setup by default in the latest version of next js? All I need is the company and the language to be passed into the page component, and I can retrieve the appropriate data. I'm hoping I can achieve this without a custom server, but I'm not sure if that's possible.